# pod update problem with gRPC-Core 1.14.0 and 1.14.1

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

My Podfile look like this

```
platform :ios, '11.2'

target 'live-quiz' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'CodableFirebase'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'CountryPickerSwift'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'SwiftySound'
end
```

I can run pod update without problem before but today after I run pod update

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Core` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
      FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
        GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "gRPC-Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
        gRPC-C++ (~> 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
          gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
            gRPC-Core (= 1.14.0)

    Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
        gRPC-ProtoRPC (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
          gRPC-ProtoRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
            gRPC (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
              gRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
                gRPC-Core (= 1.14.1)
```

It looks like gRPC-Core from gRPC-C++/Implementation and gRPC/Main use different version (1.14.0, 1.14.1) how to fix this ?

Comment: I am having the same issue, and spolied 2 days. Do you got any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please re-run

```
pod update
```

They fixed it. Please check out:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845

> Resolved issue with Firebase/Core dependencies that caused a CocoaPods error. (#1845, #8110)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a Complete CleanUp (Pods Reset)

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and the following worked for me.
Change your Podfile:

from:

```
platform :ios, '11.2'
```

to:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Comment: still have same error what command do I need to run before pod update to clean up?

Answer (score 0):

**Now : Google fix this issue in Version 5.8.1 - September 19, 2018**

From firebase support

> You're right, the issue still exist even downgrading the platform
>   version, I already coordinated this with our engineer and waiting for
>   their response. For now, I was able to install properly by downgrading
>   my Firebase/Core version to 5.7.0 i.e. 'Firebase/Core', '5.7.0'. Then
>   doing a pod install / pod update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try to add :

```
pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', '0.0.3'
```

in project's Podfile and then run :

```
pod install
```