# pod install getting stuck grpc-core 1.50.1

Tags: ios, flutter

I am unable to complete 'pod install' despite a good internet connection. Stuck for 2 hours with Flutter.

Targated ios version is: 11.0
platform :ios, '11.0'

My console:

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing DKImagePickerController (4.3.4)
Installing DKPhotoGallery (0.0.17)
Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
Installing Firebase (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.11.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (10.11.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.11.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.11.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.11.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (10.10.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (3.1.1)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.2.3)
Installing GoogleMaps (5.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.11.1)
Installing MTBBarcodeScanner (5.0.11)
Installing OrderedSet (5.0.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.2.0)
Installing SDWebImage (5.16.0)
Installing SwiftProtobuf (1.22.0)
Installing SwiftyGif (5.4.4)
Installing abseil (1.20220623.0)
Installing barcode_scan2 (0.0.1)
Installing cloud_firestore (4.8.1)
Installing file_picker (0.0.1)
Installing firebase_auth (4.6.3)
Installing firebase_core (2.14.0)
Installing firebase_messaging (14.6.3)
Installing firebase_storage (11.2.3)
Installing flutter_inappwebview (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_native_splash (0.0.1)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.50.1)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.50.1)
```

I also tried this solution [pod update problem with gRPC-Core 1.14.0 and 1.14.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397642/pod-update-problem-with-grpc-core-1-14-0-and-1-14-1) but did not work. My installation getting stuck at gRPC-Core (1.50.1)

Thanks for helping me, Really appreciated

Comment: Solved the problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, I hope this answer will help other developers

what I did:

```
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods                                                        
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I also Updated Xcode to latest version, after that I run the command in project

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: Thank you @Hasnain Elahi, I had the same problem tonight and your solution fixed it!

Comment: This one took a little time, but worked just fine... Thanks bro.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I later figured that it is naturally taking time because none of the workarounds worked.

Commands used;

```
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
```

The process "Installing gRPC-Core (1.50.1)" took around 11 minutes on Macos and it is expected to take a little more on windows and somewhat similar on linux.